# Is there any easy way to validate the presence of a HABTM relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm working on a rails project which has two models, Business and User, and the HABTM relationship between them. I would like to add a validator to the business model so businesses cannot be created or updated without at least one user.

I was told to use `validate :users, :presence => true` in the business model, but that doesn't work on associations, only db columns. Is there an easy validator for this?

**Edit**

My bad, it turns out I had a typo. `validate :users, :presence => true` totally works on associations. I'm selecting the first answer because it was Phillip's link that helped me realize this, and I'm leaving this question up in case anyone else makes the same stupid mistake.

Comment: The weird acronym is "Has and belongs to many"

Comment: I just say HABTM because 'many to many' in Rails could refer to either a HABTM or Has-Many-Through and I want to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `validates_associated`.  Docs say "Validates whether the associated object or objects are all valid. Works with any kind of association."

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :some_method

  def some_method
    # return true to validate true, return false to validate false
  end
end
```

While this may not be the built-in way, this does give you a lot of flexibility as to how you would like your model validated.